# SmartWatch 2 screenshots

Tags: sony-smartwatch

What is the recommended way to create screenshots of a SmartWatch 2 extension?

Unfortunately, notification extensions on the emulator look nothing like they look on a real device. Also my control extension that uses a layout (instead of sending an image) looks slightly different on the device emulator.

Bonus question (to Sony): Are there official device frames we are free to use?

Comment: I am also looking for a way to capture a screenshot of the Sony SmartWatch 2 screen.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the options you have are either using the emulator (as you have done) or taking photos of the physical hardware device in action.

Regarding device frames question, there is no such material available.

Comment: As for the bonus question, allow me to look it up and return with a definite answer.